# How to take into consideration gaps in time series?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, interpolation

I've been analysing what is the probability of that measurement going up or down during a week (e.g. 4 times out of 7, I have 60% chances of my measurement going up) everyday for the last 100 days, but I couldn't record 10 consecutive days, so I started again.

Lets say:

- day 1: 10
- day 2: 11
- day 3: 10
- day 4: 14 ...
- day 90: 13
- day 91: --
- day 92: --
- ... *(day 93 to 99: --)*
- day 100: --
- day 101: 16
- day 102: 15
- day 103: 15

where "--" is no data recorded for that day.

Before it was easy to read, during any 7 consecutive days the probability of the measurement going up is x, but after the gap, it's not, because the last 7 days have missed readings. What is the best way to interpret the missed readings. Should I just get rid of the gap?

Answer (score 1):

if the data is [missing at random](http://missingdata.lshtm.ac.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=76%3amissing-at-random-mar&catid=40%3amissingness-mechanisms&Itemid=96), you can skip the missing days.

if you have reason to believe that the fact that the data is missing is somehow related to the probabilities of interest, then it gets complicated. for instance, the measurement is low that it records as missing. in this case the fact it is missing is related to the fact that the measurement went down.